# Applying the Master Theorem when there are three terms?

Tags: math, big-o, recurrence, master-theorem

How would I go about solving this kind of recurrence using the Master Theorem?

> T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n<sup>2</sup> + logn

I have no idea how to go about doing this, but I'm pretty sure it is possible to solve it using Master Theorem. Do I have to ignore one of the terms? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The Master Theorem works for functions that can be written as

> T(n) = aT(n / b) + f(n)

Here, you have that a = 4, b = 2, and f(n) = n<sup>2</sup> + log n.  Notice that we're grouping "n<sup>2</sup> + log n" together as the f(n) term, rather than treating it as two separate terms.

Now that we've done that, we can apply the Master Theorem directly.  Notice that log<sub>b</sub> a = log<sub>2</sub> 4 = 2 and that f(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), so by the Master Theorem this solves to Θ(n<sup>2</sup> log n).  The reason this works is that n<sup>2</sup> + log n = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), and the Master Theorem only cares about the asymptotic complexity of f(n).  In fact, any of these recurrences can be solved the same way:

> T(n) = 4T(n / 2) + n<sup>2</sup> + 137n + 42
>
> T(n) = 4T(n / 2) + 5n<sup>2</sup> + 42n log n + 42n + 5 log n + 10<sup>6</sup>
>
> T(n) = 4T(n / 2) + 0.5n<sup>2</sup> + n log<sup>137</sup> n + n log n + n<sup>2</sup> / log n + 5

Hope this helps!